# do the work anyway

Tags: meaning, adverbs, ambiguity

a. You will have to do the work anyway.

I think here 'anyway' means 'in any case', but could it also mean 'in any manner you can'? Is the sentence ambiguous?

Comment: Dictionaries indicate that using "anyway" to mean "in any way" is obsolete.  That sense isn't used in modern English, though you may see it in some older (pre 1900) texts.

Comment: The word for 'in any manner you can' is _anyhow_.

Comment: Thank you all. So would 'You will have to do the work anyhow' have that meaning?

Comment: @KateBunting has already told you what anyhow means.

Answer (score 2):

There might be an ambiguity, but not the one you think.

"Anyway" doesn't mean "in any manner" (in modern English)

It can mean "regardless" or "despite the situation".  And this is the most common meaning, and the one that is most likely here.

It is also used to show that the sentence explains or justifies a previous sentence, or as a conversational marker to indicate a change in topic.  Although these usages would only be apparent in context, and would probably require extra punctuation.

> You'll have to the work, anyway... Let's talk about something more fun.

> You'll have to do everything that Bob does.  You'll have to do the work, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"have to do the work anyway" or "have to [action] anyway"

A common phrase indicating a requirement to complete an action. It is typically used with another sentence or phase that indicates doing something else along with the required action.  The other action can precede or follow the required.

Examples with [required action] enclosed in brackets[]

```
"We might as well have fun, we have to [do the work] anyway." 
"I can pick up some milk, I have to [go to the store] anyway." 
"We can add that error check, we have to [change the code] anyway." 
"You might as well get started, you have to [do the work] anyway."
```